# Build Angular Application for production

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, server, angular-material

Hello I am having great difficulty building my angular application for production.

I am running the 'ng build --prod' command however when i open the 'dist' folder i don't see all my components there. Is there something else i have to change or configure? When opening the 'dist' folder i see some components.

> **angular.json**

```
{
   "$schema":"./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "version":1,
   "newProjectRoot":"projects",
   "projects":{
      "app":{
         "projectType":"application",
         "schematics":{
            "@schematics/angular:component":{
               "style":"scss"
            }
         },
         "root":"",
         "sourceRoot":"src",
         "prefix":"app",
         "architect":{
            "build":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
               "options":{
                  "outputPath":"dist/app",
                  "index":"src/index.html",
                  "main":"src/main.ts",
                  "polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",
                  "tsConfig":"tsconfig.app.json",
                  "aot":false,
                  "assets":[
                     "src/favicon.ico",
                     "src/assets",
                     "src/images"
                  ],
                  "styles":[
                     "src/styles.scss"
                  ],
                  "scripts":[

                  ]
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "fileReplacements":[
                        {
                           "replace":"src/environments/environment.ts",
                           "with":"src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                     ],
                     "optimization":true,
                     "outputHashing":"all",
                     "sourceMap":false,
                     "extractCss":true,
                     "namedChunks":false,
                     "aot":true,
                     "extractLicenses":true,
                     "vendorChunk":false,
                     "buildOptimizer":true,
                     "budgets":[
                        {
                           "type":"initial",
                           "maximumWarning":"2mb",
                           "maximumError":"5mb"
                        },
                        {
                           "type":"anyComponentStyle",
                           "maximumWarning":"6kb",
                           "maximumError":"10kb"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            "serve":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
               "options":{
                  "browserTarget":"app:build"
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "browserTarget":"app:build:production"
                  }
               }
            },
            "extract-i18n":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
               "options":{
                  "browserTarget":"app:build"
               }
            },
            "test":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
               "options":{
                  "main":"src/test.ts",
                  "polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",
                  "tsConfig":"tsconfig.spec.json",
                  "karmaConfig":"karma.conf.js",
                  "assets":[
                     "src/favicon.ico",
                     "src/assets"
                  ],
                  "styles":[
                     "src/styles.scss"
                  ],
                  "scripts":[

                  ]
               }
            },
            "lint":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
               "options":{
                  "tsConfig":[
                     "tsconfig.app.json",
                     "tsconfig.spec.json",
                     "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                  ],
                  "exclude":[
                     "**/node_modules/**"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "e2e":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
               "options":{
                  "protractorConfig":"e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                  "devServerTarget":"app:serve"
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "devServerTarget":"app:serve:production"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "defaultProject":"app"
}
```

> **ts.config.json**

```
{
   "compileOnSave":false,
   "compilerOptions":{
      "baseUrl":"./",
      "outDir":"./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap":true,
      "declaration":false,
      "downlevelIteration":true,
      "experimentalDecorators":true,
      "module":"esnext",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "importHelpers":true,
      "target":"es2015",
      "typeRoots":[
         "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "lib":[
         "es2018",
         "dom"
      ]
   },
   "angularCompilerOptions":{
      "fullTemplateTypeCheck":true,
      "strictInjectionParameters":true
   }
}
```

Output when running a new build:

[image]

I now get this error when run in the console locally:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/polyfills-es2015.0fe6949bc5ff4b784062.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Check for path in angular.json file under ng -> build -> outputPath. Also, check for relatie location.

Comment: I have checked the output path and all seems correct as it is displaying as 'dist/app'

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for your application with sample application and your angular.json?

Comment: You're viewing the `out-tsc` folder which is the temporary folder used by TypeScript before WebPack bundles the packages. Please update your question with the contents of your `angular.json` and `tsconfig` files. Also, delete `/dist` before you run a build and update your question with the output from the `ng build --prod` command. Do not post these as images!

Comment: I deleted the folder and run a fresh build and updated my original post with the result

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is how it should look, you have the index.html, the favicon.ico, a css file and a bunch of .js file. Their names are weird because Angular "compile" them this way. If you visit your website it'll be working

Comment: after uploading it to iis i just see a blank page

Comment: can you try locally by just accessing your index.html from a browser first ? For IIS you need some extra steps (create the website, install URL Rewrite module, create a web.config file etc... I found this blog post with some of the steps http://sundeepkamath.in/posts/hosting-angular-application-in-iis-server/)

Comment: Yes i get the same result when running locally, so something is wrong in the compilation process

Comment: Ok in that case open your console on your browser and you might have some messages (F12 works on most browser to open the developer tools and see the console)

Comment: i updated my original post with the error from the console i receive

Comment: This is about CORS, your application probably does some API calls to another domain and this is forbidden by modern browser for security reasons (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You should try with the default angular app to see if it's working. For your own app, CORS can be allowed by different means (there is a DEV mode in google chrome that ignores it, or it can be configured on the API side)

Comment: I have made the necessary amendments to allow the API calls to be made on my API. I am assuming that i have to have my back end running as a service to then allow angular to display?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ng build --prod`, then Angular will do some actions (rough description):

- Run module bundler(e.g. WebPack).
- WebPack will see should all modules and will create a dependency tree. Then WebPack based on dependency tree will inlcude only used components in final file(bundle). It is called tree shaking.
- Then uglify happens. *Uglify* means all unnecessary whitespaces will be deleted, variable names will be shortened

So this is a reason why you don't see any components and why you cannot debug bundled files.